# Since .key is deprecated how it is possible to rename the data column in nest()?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyselect

Before `.key` was deprecated I did this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest(.key = "my_name")
```

The help of `nest()` points out that now this is performed using tidy select, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the new `nest_by` function in `dplyr` 1.0.0 which works similar to what you had previously with `nest`.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest_by(.key = "my_name")

#   cyl             my_name
#  <dbl> <list<tbl_df[,10]>>
#1     4           [11 × 10]
#2     6            [7 × 10]
#3     8           [14 × 10]
```

You can also do the same without grouping.

```
mtcars %>% nest_by(cyl, .key = "my_name")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group_cols()` to refer to grouping variables:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest(my_name = !group_cols())
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl my_name
#>   <dbl> <list>
#> 1     6 <tibble [7 × 10]>
#> 2     4 <tibble [11 × 10]>
#> 3     8 <tibble [14 × 10]>

mtcars %>% nest(my_name = !cyl)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl my_name
#>   <dbl> <list>
#> 1     6 <tibble [7 × 10]>
#> 2     4 <tibble [11 × 10]>
#> 3     8 <tibble [14 × 10]>
```

Answer (score 1):

The name can be provided directly in the arguments of nest:

```
mtcars %>% nest( my_name = -cyl )    # Nest by everything except cyl
#  # A tibble: 3 x 2
#      cyl my_name
#    <dbl> <list>
#  1     6 <tibble [7 × 10]>
#  2     4 <tibble [11 × 10]>
#  3     8 <tibble [14 × 10]>
```

Comment: This works but seems to introduce some redundancy as it requires repeating in the argument of nest() all the grouping variables.